# Can Job 14:12 be interpreted as an eschatological statement about a future resurrection of the dead?

Tags: revelation, job, eschatology, resurrection

Job 14:12 (ESV):

> so **a man lies down and rises not again**; **till the heavens are no more** he will not awake or be roused out of his sleep.

Did Job imply that there would be an eschatological/apocalyptic kind of event in the distant future, in which the heavens would cease to exist ("till the heavens are no more"), perhaps replaced by a new heaven and a new earth (see Revelation 21:1), and only THEN the resurrection of the dead would take place (hence the word "till", suggesting a delay, a waiting period until the resurrection)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Job 14 is a discourse, a lament about the finality of death.

- V2 - Like a flower, he comes forth, then withers away; like a fleeting shadow, he does not endure.
- V21 - If his sons receive honor, he does not know it; if they are brought low, he is unaware.

V12 is another statement about the unconsciousness of death:

- so a man lies down [in death] and does not rise. Until the heavens are no more,
  he will not be awakened or roused from sleep [remains unconscious in death].

Thus, Job 14 is simply about death and says nothing about the resurrection.  What happens at that time is another matter.  However, we do find a direct reference to the great eschatological resurrection in Job 19:23-27 -

> Oh, that my words were recorded, that they were written on a scroll,
> that they were inscribed with an iron tool on lead, or engraved in
> rock forever!
>
> I know that my redeemer lives, and that in the end he will stand on
> the earth. And after my skin has been destroyed, yet in my flesh I
> will see God; I myself will see him with my own eyes—I, and not
> another. How my heart yearns within me!

Note the Pulpit commentary in Job 14:12 -

> Verse 12. - So man lieth down, and riseth not. This is not an absolute
> denial of a final resurrection, since Job is speaking of the world as
> it lies before him, not of eventualities. Just as he sees the land
> encroach upon the sea, and remain land, and the river-courses, once
> dried up, remain dry, so he sees men descend into the grave and remain
> there, without rising up again. This is the established order of
> nature as it exists before his eyes. Till the heavens be no more, they
> shall not awake. This order of things, Job believes, rightly enough,
> will continue as long as the heavens and the earth endure. What will
> happen afterwards he does not so much as inquire. It is remarked,
> ingeniously, that Job's words, though not intended in this sense,
> exactly "coincide with the declarations of the New Testament, which
> make the resurrection simultaneous with the breaking up of the visible
> universe" (Canon Cook). Nor be raised out of their sleep. If "the
> glimmer of a hope" of the resurrection appears anywhere in verse.
> 10-12, it is in the comparison of death to a sleep, which is
> inseparably connected in our minds with an awakening. Job 14:12